# How can I use the data received as readtable as input of audioread? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have 30000 aiff files named audio1 ~ 30000.

And there is a csv file consisting of selected file names among them. (About 7000)

I want to audioread only the aiff data in the list of csv files.

I applied the audioread function immediately after receiving the csv file with the readtable function, but received an error message that only a string or char type vector can come as the input of the audioread.

Below is my short code.

Please help. Thanks.

```
    clc;close all;clear all;
    T = readtable('train_py.csv');   
    fs = 2000;    %All aiff files have a sampling frequency of 2000 Hz.
    y = zeros(length(T), fs);  

    for i = 1:length(T)
    y(i,:) = audioread(T(i));
    end
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: We cannot run your code without your csv file. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]